# How do char* pointers work in C? How are they stored?

Tags: pointers

I'm confused in understanding how pointers to `char` work.

What is the difference between using `char *s = "car";` and `s = "India";`?

And what about `char **s`?

How will these be stored?

Comment: Please read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/ . Strings are character array in c so character pointer just keep the base address (offset)

Comment: **s , this one is double pointer, used to keep address of pointer. must read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-pointer-pointer-pointer-c/

Comment: I think this is a valid question, why is this question closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *s = "car";` and `s = "India";` are the same thing except for the fact that `char *s = "car";` defines (creates) a new `s` variable which didn't exist before, while `s = "India";` reuses the existing `s`. In both cases `s` is a variable pointer to the first character of the string which is created in a non writable part of the data space. i.e. You can change `s` to another string (e.g. set it to `"India"` or increment it), but you cannot change the pointed memory (e.g. you can't do `s[0]='e'`).

`char **p;` just defines a pointer to a pointer (to a string), so you could write `p=&s;` and if you then wrote `*p="Terminator";` `s` would now point to a new `"terminator"` string.

There is another case that you should compare with the first two, which is `char s[20] = "Hello";` In this case, `s` is not a variable but a constant pointer to a variable 20 bytes space, in which you have stored `"Hello\0"`. In this case, you **CANNOT** point `s` to another string as in `s="turlututu";`, but you can change the content of the 20 bytes space, providing you do not overflow outside this space and keep the content properly terminated with a `'\0'` (not terminating your string is not a syntax error, but it is a dangerous practice).

Answer (score 1):

**1st case**

```
char* s = "car";
```

In this case you declaring a `char` pointer and at the same time assigning it a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), in other words, making it point to the beginning of the string literal.

**2nd case**

```
char* s;
//some code;
s = "india";
```

This is the same as first, the difference is that you are first declaring the pointer, and later assigning it the string literal.

**3rd case**

```
char** s;
```

Is a pointer to a pointer to `char` or double pointer to `char`, [take this sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OLTWYbIsyXyr3Dav):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char* ptr1 = "abc";
   char** ptr2;
   ptr2 = &ptr1;
   printf("%s", *ptr2);
}
```

Thhis means that `ptr2` is pointing to `ptr1` pointer to `char` (so it's a pointer to pointer to `char`), through indirection `ptr2` can be used to access the beggining of the string pointed by `ptr1`.

**Output**

```
abc
```

Where the string literal is stored varies deppending on the platform, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589963/6865932) has some details, as does the link I provided for string literal documentation.

> String literals are not modifiable (and in fact may be placed in read-only memory such as .rodata). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

String literals like `"car"` and `"India"` are stored in arrays of character type such that they are available over the lifetime of the program.  Under most circumstances, when an *expression* of array type appears in the code, it is implicitly converted ("decays") to an expression of pointer type, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So suppose our `"car"` string is stored as an array of `char` starting at address `0x8000`:

```
         +---+
0x8000:  |'c'|
         +---+
0x8001:  |'a'|
         +---+
0x8002:  |'r'|
         +---+
0x8003:  | 0 |
         +---+
```

When you write

```
char *s = "car";
```

the *expression* `"car"` is converted from type "4-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element - `0x8000`.  So, that `0x8000` address is written to `s`<sup>1</sup>:

```
   +--------+
s: | 0x8000 |
   +--------+
```

Later on, when you write

```
s = "India";
```

the address of the first element of the array that stores `"India"` is written to `s`.

Here's a practical example.  I've written a small utility that prints out the addresses and contents of multiple variables.  Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  char *s = "car";

  char *names[] = { "s", "\"car\"", "\"India\"" };
  void *addrs[] = { &s, "car", "India" };
  size_t sizes[] = { sizeof s, sizeof "car", sizeof "India" };

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 3, stdout );

  s = "India";

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 3, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

Here's how it looks on my system - first we look at the strings themselves:

```
      "car"     0x104f2ff71   63   61   72   00    car.

    "India"     0x104f2ff88   49   6e   64   69    Indi
                0x104f2ff8c   61   00   00   00    a...
```

The string `"car"` is stored starting at address `0x104f2ff71`, and the string `"India"` is stored starting at address `0x104f2ff88`.

Now we look at `s`:

```
          s  0x7ffeeacd0a10   71   ff   f2   04    q...
             0x7ffeeacd0a14   01   00   00   00    ....
```

`s` is stored starting at address `0x7ffeeacd0a10`, and it's *contents* are the address of the string literal `"car"`.  Since x86 is little-endian, multi-byte values have to be read right-to-left.

After we write

```
s = "India";
```

our memory looks like this:

```
          s  0x7ffeeacd0a10   88   ff   f2   04    ....
             0x7ffeeacd0a14   01   00   00   00    ....
```

Now `s` is storing the address of the array containing `"India"`.

> what is char **s? How it will be stored?

You can have pointers to pointers:

```
char **s2 = &s;
```

`s2` just stores the address of the variable `s`.  Pointers to pointers come up when you're dealing with arrays of pointers, or when you're passing a pointer to a function and you want the function to be able to write a new pointer value.

Different pointer types *may* have different representations - the only guarantees are:

- `char *` and `void *` have the same representation and alignment;
- pointers to qualified types have the same representation and alignment as pointers to the corresponding unqualified type (i.e., `int *` and `const int *` are stored the same way);
- All struct pointer types have the same representation and alignment;
- All union pointer types have the same representation and alignment;

So it's possible for a `char **` object to be stored differently from a `char *` object.  On most modern systems like x86, all pointer types are stored the same way, but there are oddballs out there where that's not the case.

---

1. In a declaration, the `*` operator is simply part of the type; it is not dereferencing anything.  We're storing the value to `s`, not to what `s` *points to*.